# Plugins wish list

Tags: plugin-development, plugins

> Would it be a great idea to post here your plugins wish list? Just post it in the comments so the community can vote for it. I can collect the wishes here.
> Developers can comment if the plugin is in development.

## Wish list:

**Comment plugin**

- low is working on it?

**Form builder or processor**

- [Sprout Email](http://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/email)
- Better control over email HTML
- Support for Mailchimp etc
- Save form data as an entry

**Image editor**

- [Dukt Image Editor (for EE)](https://dukt.net/ee/image-editor)

**Postmaster / Notification email system**

- [Objective HTML](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/postmaster) - [Dukt Notifications](https://dukt.net/craft/notifications) (still to premature).
- Third party email support: MailChimp, CampaignMonitor,
  SendGrid, Postmark, PostageApp, Mandrill, Mailgun
- CRON support

**Private asset sources**

- [Safelink by Dukt](https://dukt.net/craft/safelink)

**Reefine**

- [Reefine allows your users to easily filter, search and refine your entries](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/reefine)

**Translation manager in CP**

**What more?**

- *Add it as an answer*

Comment: Some wishes: "Dashboard widget control over users/usergroups", "CP menu control", "Multiple reordering of entries in sets based on different parameters like categories, tags, entries".

Comment: Can you be more specific? And post it as an answer? So people can like or dislike it.

Comment: This "question" does not fit the Q/A format of Stack Exchange and because of this it is Off-Topic and is likely to be closed. But what about converting it into a ["Community Wiki"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) post? I have't completely understand how these wiki pages work, but maybe this question fits that format better?

Comment: How do you change the topic to a Community wiki? Can't find it.

Comment: Hi Johannes, this question would be a better fit for the [Google+](https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/106505340287442511226) forum. Since it's not about a specific programming issue, or even a "What are the best resources for X?" type of question, it's simply not a good fit for Stack Exchange. This question can be boiled down to "What do you desire?", which is not historically useful, nor is it a great way to communicate feature requests to P&T or other plugin devs.

Comment: Can we convert this topic to a community wiki? I would really love to see a plugins wish list. Google+ forum is  like a ghost town now.

Comment: Sorry, the question is simply a bad fit for Stack Exchange. The whole purpose of the SE structure is to ask a _specific_ question to which people can try to provide the _best possible_ answer. There is no "best possible" answer to this question, nor does it solve a specific problem. As much as I also would like to see a plugin wishlist somewhere, it really just doesn't belong on Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 4):

Wish: "Reordering of entries based on custom sets"

This wish is similar to the EE addon Low Reorder. Craft has the awesome Structure support but sometime you need the ability to be able to make custom reordering within the same section more then one time.

Answer (score 3):

I'd personally love to see a Freeform like plugin created. There are ways of making it happen by using Sprout Email or P&T's Contact Form, but when someone fills out a form it would be nice to have it saved as an Entry into a Section.

Answer (score 1):

**Private asset sources**, see [Dukt Safe Link](https://dukt.net/craft/safelink)

Comment: In the wish list

Answer (score 0):

**Postmaster**: isn't this similar to [sprout email](http://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/email/)?

Comment: No. With Sprout forms you can create forms for Contacts, Projects, Leads, Surveys, Contests, Registration, RSVPs, or whatever else you need.

Postmaster: Postmaster is the definitive solution for emailing channel entry data. It can send emails for anything using hooks. Follow a user, subscribe to mailinglist, send email to follower when there is a new entry etc et.

Comment: Sorry, I typed the wrong plugin name. I meant sprout email which allows you to send create campaigns from channel entries, send notifications, ... Also has third party support for Campaign Monitor and Mailchimp.   Updated my original answer

Answer (score 0):

Wish: "Dashboard widget control"

The ability to manage users and/or usergroups dashboard widgets globally without having to login to each user.